# SQL: An alternative to Group By approach using Partion By

Tags: sql

I have a table in a DW system (say AWS SnowFlake):

```
UPC_CODE    A_PRICE     A_QTY    DATE       COMPANY_CODE    A_CAT
1001        100.25       2     2021-05-06      1             PB
1001        2122.75      10    2021-05-01      1             PB
1002        212.75       5     2021-05-07      2             PT
1002        3100.75      10    2021-05-01      2             PB
```

What I am looking for is :

```
For each UPC_CODE and COMPANY_CODE the latest data should be picked up
```

So the resultant table should be like below:

```
UPC_CODE    A_PRICE     A_QTY    DATE       COMPANY_CODE    A_CAT
1001        100.25       2     2021-05-06      1             PB
1002        212.75       5     2021-05-07      2             PT
```

Approach: Below SQL string

```
SELECT  UPC_CODE,A_PRICE,A_QTY,MAX(DATE) AS F_DATE,COMPANY_CODE,A_CAT 
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY 1,2,3,5,6
```

Can I have an alternative approach using `partionby()`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `GROUP BY` query doesn't really do what you have in mind.  One canonical approach here uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPC_CODE, COMPANY_CODE ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT UPC_CODE, A_PRICE, A_QTY, DATE, COMPANY_CODE, A_CAT
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you did want to use a `GROUP BY` approach, here is one way to do that:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UPC_CODE, COMPANY_CODE, MAX(DATE) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY UPC_CODE, COMPANY_CODE
) t2
    ON t2.UPC_CODE = t1.UPC_CODE AND
       t2.COMPANY_CODE = t1.COMPANY_CODE AND
       t2.MAX_DATE = t1.DATE;
```

Comment: great!! for the 1st approach, can I use `SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1`?

Comment: @pythondumb Yes, you can, _but_ keep in mind that if you do `SELECT *` you'll also select the `rn` row number defined in the CTE.  As you may not want that, instead list out all columns you really do want to see.

Comment: Those are nice approaches. But you only grouped by `UPC_CODE`, whereas the OP wanted to group by the combination of `UPC_CODE` and `COMPANY_CODE`. If `UPC_CODE` and `COMPANY_CODE` values are always paired, that wouldn't be a problem, but to me, that's not clear from the question. Perhaps the OP should be more explicit about that. Anyway, I suppose your two approaches could be easily fixed to include both `UPC_CODE` and `COMPANY_CODE` in the group? Or did you intentionally only include `UPC_CODE`?

Comment: @BartHofland You're right, I didn't read closely enough.  Just add `COMPANY_CODE` to each group/partition.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake (which your first line suggests), you would use [`QUALIFY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html):

```
SELECT UPC_CODE, A_PRICE, A_QTY, DATE AS F_DATE, COMPANY_CODE, A_CAT 
FROM <table_name>
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BYUPC_CODE, A_PRICE, A_QTY, COMPANY_CODE, A_CAT
                           ORDER BY DATE DESC
                          ) = 1;
```